# JS - Эмуляция кнопки "назад" в javascript

Tags: javascript

Хочу написать кнопку, при нажатии на которую будет эмулироваться кнопка "назад", как в браузере. Есть такая функция в javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В HTML5 появилось [history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/History_API), которое поддерживает использование браузерной истории

```
<button onclick="window.history.back()">Кнопка назад</button>
```

Вы можете вынести код из onclick в другую функцию, если хотите добавить еще какие-то действия, которые должны произойти до перехода назад.

```
<button onclick="GoBack()">Кнопка назад</button>

<script>
let GoBack = function (){
    //здесь можно добавить обработку какой-нибудь логики, при желании
    window.history.back();
};
</script>
```

Comment: Не хочу заводить новую тему, посему спрошу тут. У меня на странице есть переход на новую страницу. С главной на дочернюю, грубо говоря. На дочерней странице список треков, по которым можно кликнуть и пойдет воспроизведение. При переходе на дочернюю страницу и последующим нажатием кнопки "назад" в системе андроид, происходит возврат на главную страницу - это то, что мне нужно. Но если я начинаю клацать по трекам, то что бы вернуться на главную, мне нужно кнопку "назад" нажать ровно столько раз, сколько раз я кликнул по ссылкам - это то, чего я хочу избежать. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Мне кажется, что для этого лучше задать новый вопрос, так как браузер для андроида, судя по всему работает по другому, да и желательно иметь какой-то пример кода страницы с треками, который бы помог выявить причину такого поведения.